# Which Android Platform/API is required to develop honeycomb tablet android applications?

Tags: android, sdk, android-3.0-honeycomb

I want to create an Android app for the Honeycomb tablet.

What Android Platform/API Level is required to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the 3.0 because this is the first Honeycomb release. You should not have backward comptability issues. But using the latest (3.2) release will cause problems with the earlier releases.

Answer (score 1):

For Honeycomb you should use android 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create an Android app for the Honeycomb tablet.

Sweet!!!

> What Android Platform/API Level is required to do so?

Honeycomb (API v11)